# FBSDK_CANOPENURL_FBAPI Undeclared Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I added Facebook share SDK via pods and I am getting

> FBSDK_CANOPENURL_FBAPI
> identifier not found error in FBSDKShareDialogue.m , I am attaching the reference image.[image]

Do I need to add anything else too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBSDKCoreKit was 4.10 and ShareKit was 4.11 , so pods update solved the problem.